# Authorization on a Blazor Server app using Microsoft Identity (Azure AD Authentication) doesn't work

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

Forgive me if this is an obvious question with an easy answer but for the life of me I cannot get my app to behave the way I want.

When I normally use MS Identity in my Blazor apps I can create roles and policies which all come from a SQL database.  For this B2B app I need to use Azure AD and the groups within there to authenticate and authorize access.

At the moment the whole app is secured because the default policy is being applied to all parts of the site but I would like to use `[Authorize(Policy = "ViewCustomer")]` for example to ensure users have the right permission to view a particular part.

I am sure that this part of my program.cs is missing policies and is part of the problem:

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{    
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

Trouble is I don't have a clue how to create these so they refer to groups (or similar) in the Azure AD tenant.  My complete program.cs is:

```
using DevExpress.Blazor;
using DataModel.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using BlazorUI.Hubs;
using BlazorUI.Services;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Config;
using BlazorUI.Services.Interfaces;
using DataModel.Xero.Interface;
using DataModel.DickerData.Interfaces;
using DataModel.DickerData;
using DataModel.Xero;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
.AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{    
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISettingService, SettingService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IXeroService, XeroService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDickerDataService, DickerDataService>();

//XERO SETTINGS
builder.Services.Configure<XeroConfiguration>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("XeroConfiguration"));

//DICKER DATA SETTINGS
builder.Services.Configure<DickerConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DickerDataConfiguration"));

//DEVEXPRESS
builder.Services.AddDevExpressBlazor(configure => configure.BootstrapVersion = BootstrapVersion.v5);

//ENTITY FRAMEWORK
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection"));
    options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();   
});

var app = builder.Build();

//DEVEXPRESS
builder.WebHost.UseWebRoot("wwwroot");
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

//REGISTER SIGNAL R HUBS
app.MapHub<MessageHub>(MessageHub.PATHTOHUB);

app.Run();
```

Thank you so much to anyone that may be able to enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add app roles to your application, assign them to selected users and obtain them as claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) so they can be used in tandem with your [AuthorizeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizeattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Alternatively, you can further customize or augment the authorization criteria using [Claim Based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in tandem with your policy.